# Fuzzy search for directory when you don't know the full directory name

Tags: ido, find-file, ido-find-file, flx-ido, fuzzy-search

Say I want to find a directory like:

```
foo/bar/bazz/bar/directory_name_looking_for/stuff.xml
```

And I don't know the intermediate directory paths, or the full directory name, but remember that the directory has the word looking in it.

I am using flx-ido like so:

```
(require 'flx-ido)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
```

Which joins very well for when I want to do things like `f/b/b/b/d/stuff`

Is there a good way to type `looking` and get a list of suggestions?

Comment: You may be interested in the answers to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4340949/3084001).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small script, and then integrated with helm to achieve similar effect. Luckily I wrote about it on my blog (while trying to kickstart my blogging habit). Here it is:

https://harizvi.wordpress.com/2013/03/31/poor-mans-everything-on-mac-osx/

Should work on Linux transparently. On Windows, you can plug in the actual Everything app that I was trying to mimic.

Comment: Please copy the answer here, or it's just a link-only answer.

Answer (score 1):

Install find-file-in-project, https://github.com/technomancy/find-file-in-project

`M-x find-directory-in-project-by-selected`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the standard `(icomplete-mode t)` in my init-file. Then for

**Directories:** `C-x d /*/*/src` -> gives me as a candidate /usr/local/src, with other word it is working for your scenario when you know the depth of the interesting directory and for

**Files:** `C-x C-f /u/l/s/e` returns the completion of -> /usr/local/src/emacs, or for

**Functions:** `C-h f a-r-m` -> one candidate is e.g. `auto-revert-mode`. Also for

**Buffers:** `C-x b d.`-> returns candidate buffers beginning with *d* and a file suffix. Finally

**Code:** `a-r-m C-M-i` writes the completion *auto-r-mod* into the buffer and a completion buffer.